# computing the marginal density of minimum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a question on Iran's Bachelor's entrance exam that is as follows:

> let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be random variables picked randomly from the distribution:
> $f(x) = 2(1-x)$  for $(0<x<1)$ what is the marginal  density of $V=nY_n$ where $Y_n = min(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$

here's what I did:
$$\begin{equation} F(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        2x-x^2 & \text{if } 0<x<1&\\
        0 & \text{if } x<0\\
        1 & \text{if }x>1
    \end{array} \right\} \end{equation}$$
$$F_{Y_n}(y) = 1-(1-F(y))^n$$
$$f_{Y_n}(y)=\frac{d(1-(1-F(y))^n)}{dx}=n(1-F(y))^{n-1}f(y)=2n(1-y)^{2n-1}, \text{ if } 0<y<1$$
$$f_V(v) = f_{Y_n}(\frac{1}{n}(v))\frac{d(\frac{1}{n}v)}{dv}=2(1-\frac{1}{n}v)^{2n-1}, \text{ if } 0<v<n$$
the asnwer should be a $V \sim Exp(2)$ (exponential with mean $\frac{1}{2}$). I couldn't be farther off, but I can't figure out the problem with my solution.

Edit: the question does mention limit I just mistranslated it.

Comment: $F_{Y_n}(y) =1- (1-F(y))^n$ not  $(1-F(y))^n$.  It does not make much difference

Comment: The exponential only appears in the limit.  Note that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (1-\frac ax)^{bx} = e^{-ab}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have $f_V(v) = 2\cdot  (1-\frac{1}{n}v)^{2n-1}=\frac{2}{1-\frac{v}n}\cdot (1-\frac{v}{n})^{n}\cdot (1-\frac{v}{n})^{n}  \text{, if } 0<v<n$

Now you take the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_V(v)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2}{1-\frac{v}n}\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{v}{n}\right)^{n}\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{v}n\right)^n$$

With the hint in the comment of [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) you get the desired result.